# Xamarin ios visual bug

Tags: ios, xamarin

i have a strange bug in my xamarin IOS app.
From half to the bottom, there is a pattern that appears on top of the other controls.
Even if i remove almost everything in the view, the problem is still there.
If i delete everything in appshell, the only change is the color.

Android app works no problem.
I use Synfusion control on most view.
The problem is there on all my views.

[bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yi6xZ.png)

Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like some icons, enlarged, and overlaid on top of each other. Double-check syncfusion's instructions for using their xamarin controls on iOS. Maybe missing some initialization? Make sure the syncfusion init line and the xamarin init lines are in the order they specify. (I don't remember which comes first.) If that isn't the issue, remove EVERYTHING from your view, see if it still happens.

Comment: You are right. It was the icon from the <tabbar> tag in appShell.  It seems the tabbar on ios take half the screen. Thank you :)